# Laravel + Paypal + cUrl + Ionic

Tags: php, laravel, ionic-framework, paypal

I was hoping you could help me troubleshoot this issue I'm having with trying to use curl with Paypal in Laravel. I'm integrating it with Ionic. It breaks when I press the button to purchase and the app gives an error of:

> Cannot GET /undefined.

I'm following a tutorial and the outcome should be that by pressing the button to purchase, the app would redirect the user to Paypal. Note that after I get the error pressing the button, the console goes to blank on developer tools (maybe because it is trying to redirect the user to paypal, outside the app?), so I can't really investigate further the errors, but the ones I could see in a blink before it goes blank are the ones I mention!

The code below is exactly the same the tutorial I'm following, I know it might not say much as there could be issues in other places, but there's that. I'm pasting the code in the Laravel api.php file, and the error I get shows me the output : "error purchasing! - 1" which is the message I'm printing in the second last "else" block from the Laravel code, this might be a hint of the issue that I'm not being able to catch. I'm also pasting the function in the ionic app that calls the api one.

I know I might be giving limited info, so let me know what other information you need for this, or even help on how I can debug this further will be greatly appreciated!

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/paypal', function (Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    $data = $request->all();
    $list_products_id = $data;

    $products = [];
    $total = 0;

    $titles = '';

    foreach($list_products_id as $key => $value) {
        $product = Product::find($value);
        if($product){
            $products[$key] = $product;
            $total += $product->price;
            $titles .= $product->title." ";
        } 
    }

    if($total){

        $paypal = config('app.paypal', "sandbox");

       if($paypal == "sandbox"){
            $userProvider = '';
            $pwdProvider = '';
            $signProvider = '';
            $url = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
            $url2 = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?%s';

       } else {
            $userProvider = '';
            $pwdProvider = '';
            $signProvider = '';   
            $url = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';
            $url2 = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?%s';
       }

       $data = [];
       $data['USER'] = $userProvider;
       $data['PWD'] = $pwdProvider;
       $data['SIGNATURE'] = $signProvider;
       $data['METHOD'] = 'SetExpressCheckout';
       $data['VERSION'] = '108';
       $data['LOCALECODE'] = 'en_US';

       $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'] = "Products Orders";
       $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0'] = $titles;

       $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = number_format($total, 2).'';

       $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'EUR';
       $data['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'] = 'Sale';

       $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'] = '100'; //number of the same product the user is ordering
       $data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'] = number_format($total, 2).'';

       $data['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] = $titles;

       $data['CANCELURL'] = url('/');
       $data['RETURNURL'] = url('/');

      // curl

      $data = http_build_query($data);

      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

      $response =  curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);

      $nvp = array();

      if (preg_match_all('/(?<name>[^\=]+)\=(?<value>[^&]+)&?/', $response, $matches)) {
          foreach ($matches['name'] as $offset => $name) {
              $nvp[$name] = urldecode($matches['value'][$offset]);
          }
      }

      if(isset($nvp['ACK']) && $nvp['ACK'] == "Success" ){
        $query = array(
                'cmd'    => '_express-checkout',
                'token'  => $nvp['TOKEN']
            );

            $redirectURL = sprintf($url2, http_build_query($query));

            return ['date'=>$redirectURL];
      }else{
        return ['status'=>'error purchasing! - 1'];

      }

    }

    echo "total: " . $total;
    return ['status'=>'error purchasing! - 2'];
});
```

Below is the Ionic code:

```js
purchase() {
    console.log("Order");
    if (!this.user) {
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      return;
    }
    this.cartProvider.purchase(this.cart, this.user).subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res) {
          console.log(res);
          // this.showToast("top", "Checkout completed successfully!");
          window.location.href = res.date;
          this.removeAll();
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        this.showToast("top", "Error checking out");
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: first I think you may use: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle which offer promise and other features.

Comment: You can use the "preserve log" option in Chrome DevTools to keep the console from clearing when the url changes.

Comment: It's not clear where you are seeing the error "Cannot GET /undefined".  Is this in the browser, in the console, or in your `laravel.log` file?  Seems like you're trying to navigate to a URL based on a variable that is undefined, perhaps the line `window.location.href = res.date;` . try commenting that out and see what happens.  If nothing else maybe you can see what is being logged to the console.

Comment: @BizzyBob Thanks for the tips! So the error "Cannot GET /undefined" appears in the app (not the console), and now with the "preserve log" I can see that it only says: 
{status: "error purchasing! - 1"}
GET http://localhost:8100/undefined 404 (Not Found)
Navigated to http://localhost:8100/undefined

Now, if I remove the line: window.location.href = res.date;
The console errors stop at the "{status: "error purchasing! - 1"}" (the same "else" block error) , no undefined error (it doesn't redirect me anywhere, and the app stays normal - but it doesn't take me to paypal as expected :(

Comment: do `console.log(res)` and see what it contains.  Doesn't seem like you'd want to use the `date` property of the response as a place to redirect to.  Maybe there's a different property you're supposed to be using.

Answer (score 0):

@BizzyBob thanks for your suggestions, in the end it turned out I added a wrong value for a parameter:

$data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'] = '1';

Previously I had:

$data['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'] = '100';

changing that to "1" resolved the issue. Really hard to spot in my opinion as we have been looking everywhere else for the solution... So, just a quick reminder for anyone out there to always double check parameter values and whatnot, as they could be causing errors that you might be trying to debug in complete different places!